# About file upload using angular to show file data on console

Tags: angular

So, i want something like when we upload a file we have to show the file data on the browser console i already tried with .txt file but it has to work for .dox and .pptx file and pdf file
so anyone can do it

Answer (score 0):

that is a good question by the way

finally i got solution for you use just need to read the data from the file and once it done than you shoud console those data as read as text

here i'm attaching the reference stacblitz code for you [stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y6mhdl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

you can have look once

Comment: hi, bro i saw it but this is the problem i have i can't show the data what's on file  its coming decrypted. that is where I'm not getting the data  the data on file like we have a bio data about ours

Comment: @nikhileswar so you are telling that the file contains the encrypted data is it ?

Comment: yes, and i can't access it because it comes in like compress file data

Comment: so you want to display decrepted data in console. Encryption to decription conversion right ??

Comment: Yeah, sry i'm little busy can you do it

Comment: okay will do for you give some time

Comment: Np, take your time it will help both of us in feature